# Is there a way to display multiple youtube videos (using their youtube id) using a for/while loop?

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, youtube

I have a list of youtube IDs that I would like to loop through and return a video within my Jupyter Notebook for each ID. Whenever I run the loop the video doesn't display.

```py
from IPython.display import YouTubeVideo

def show_vid(video_id):
        return YouTubeVideo(video_id, width=800, height=300)
    
video_id_list = ['WSbgixdC9g8',
'GgIxIZhEAs0',
'eB2OpurOFhk',
'cd0Fy92_w_s']

for i in video_id_list:
    show_vid(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Jupyter notebooks display the latest variable of the executed cell, that's why a single YouTube video like this works:

```py
from IPython.display import YouTubeVideo
YouTubeVideo(video_id, width=800, height=300)
```

However for multiple videos you can display an array of videos by using:

```py
[show_vid(video_id) for video_id in video_id_list]
```

instead of:

```py
for i in video_id_list:
    show_vid(i)
```